# Cannot upload a file when automating tests

Tags: html, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, protractor

I have been uploading files using the same function throughout my automated tests:

```js
        var path = require('path');
         //the file to upload
        fileToUpload,
         //this is variable that inserts the path to find file to upload
        absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
         //inserts the path
        uploadPathLink.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

The  button/link in my html looks like this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-select" data-bind="click: assosiateLogoImage">
```

The Upload form in my html looks like this:

```html
<form id="uploadForm" action="https://iplan.preview.s3.amazonaws.com/" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="uploadIFrame" method="post">
  <div class="file-input" data-bind="css: {'ie': isIE}">
    <input id="logoFile" type="file" data-bind="event:{ 'change': handleLogoSelection }" name="file">
  </div>
</form>
```

The upload form opens and then just hangs.  I know the path to the file is working because its the same file I am uploading in other parts of the app, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was sending the absolute path to the wrong element, should have looked like this:

```
 var path = require('path');
    //the file to upload
    fileToUpload,
        //this is variable that inserts the path to find file to upload
        absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    //inserts the path
    $('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(absolutePath);
};
```